# Is there a DotNetOpenAuth equivalent that runs on a LAMP stack?

Tags: php, python, ruby, perl, dotnetopenauth

I really love the way the StackExchange family of sites allow someone to log in using their OpenID or OAuth provider, which has been open-sourced as [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).  This is absolutely wonderful, but I am unable to use it on a *AMP stack.

Is there anything analogous that runs in PHP, Perl, Python or Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

For Perl there's [`Net::OAuth`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-OAuth/), and there looks to be an as-yet-unreleased [`Catalyst::Controller::OAuth`](http://dev.catalystframework.org/repos/Catalyst/trunk/Catalyst-Controller-OAuth/), but what the status of that last one is is unknown (other than the [OAuth code page](http://oauth.net/code/) says they're "working on" it).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication::Credential::OpenID](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Catalyst-Plugin-Authentication-Credential-OpenID-0.03/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Authentication/Credential/OpenID.pm) - OpenID credential for Catalyst::Auth framework

Answer (score 0):

For Perl you want [`Net::OpenID::Consumer`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenID%3a%3aConsumer). Development is getting started on it again so in the next few weeks you should see new versions with some of the major bugs fixed and new docs explaining how to use them properly (it can be hard to figure out right now). See the [openid-perl](http://groups.google.com/group/openid-perl) group for more details.